# node js REPL dump context

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm looking for a way to access the variables / functions defined in a node js REPL:

```
$ node
> x = 5
5
> eval('y = 9')
9
> who <----- something like this maybe?
```

EDIT:
The expected output I look for is:

```
x
y
```

Comment: Do you want to simply access your x variable? or something else

Comment: _"I'm looking for a way to access the variables / functions defined in a node js REPL"_ You can access `x` and `y` by name, e.g. `console.log(y)`.

Comment: `global` contains the global variables, but also some more properties.

Comment: @jabaa great ! is there any way to filter the variables / functions from there?

Comment: You could read the initial properties at the start of your session and remove them later.